# Match a string in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES 2.4.0

i have to match a string it will be like this `"{hi} {ARE} {how} {You}"`

I given query like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {

        "simple": "{hi} {ARE} {how} {You}"

    }
  }
}
```

In the output it is showing all the documents rather than the documents that match the exact string (i.e simple) value.

NOTE: This is analysed at mapping level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match all the keywords in the same order, you should use `match_phrase`

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "simple": "{hi} {ARE} {how} {You}"
        }
    }
}
```

In case you don't need the words in the same order, but want only all these words to be present in the search results, then use `match` with `operator`.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "simple": {      
                "query": "{hi} {ARE} {how} {You}",
                "operator": "and"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..it helped